Proof of $|\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu (n)}{n}| \leq 1$.
I'm reading a proof of $$\left|\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\right| \leq 1$$ for all $x \geq 1$. If $x < 2$, there is only one term in the  sum, $\mu(1) = 1$. Now assume that $x \geq 2$. For each real $y$, let $\{y\} = y - [y]$. Then $$1 = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n)\left [\frac{x}{n}\right] = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left(\frac{x}{n}-\left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\}\right) = x\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu (n)}{n} - \sum_{n \leq x} \mu (n)
\left \{\frac{x}{n}\right\}.$$ Since $0 \leq \{y\} <1$ this implies $x |\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu (n)}{n}| = |1+\sum_{n \leq x} \mu (n) \{\frac{x}{n}\}| \leq 1 + \sum_{n \leq x} \{
\frac{x}{n}\} = 1 + \{x\} +\sum_{2\leq n \leq x} \{\frac{x}{n}\} <$ $ 1 + \{x\} + [x] - 1 = x.$
And dividing by $x$, we obtain the target inequality. I'm confused about how the book gets $1 + \{x\} +\sum_{2\leq n \leq x} \{\frac{x}{n}\} < 1 + \{x\} + [x] - 1$.

The sum  $ \sum_{2\leq n \leq x} \{\frac{x}{n}\} $ has $[x]-1 $ terms, each of which is less than $1$.  Do you see it now?

Yes! Thanks for your help!
